# Can I run moderated mediation analysis on the a, b or c paths alone using mediation R package?

Tags: r, interaction, mediation

I am trying to run a moderated mediation analysis and I would like to know if there's an influence of the moderator in all paths, together and separately, with `mediation` R package. However, when I try to run the code for the paths separately, or more precisely, when I don't have the mediator in both equations (below) I get the error:

```
Error in [.data.frame(pred.data.t, , vl) : undefined columns selected.
```

My code, for the example of b path alone:

```
model_fitM <- lm(Mediator ~ X, data=mydata)

model_fitY <- lm(Y ~ X + Mediator * Moderator, data=mydata)

model_MedMod <- mediate(model_fitM, model_fitY, treat=X, 
                        mediator=Mediator)

test.modmed(model_MedMod, covariates.1 = list(Moderator = 1), 
            covariates.2 = list(Moderator = 0))
```

Is there a way of running this with this package, or it simply doesn't allow for comparisons of the two models when only one has the Moderator?